# Trying to create multiple development sites with git worktree

Tags: git

I will explain my setup first, then my question is between the underscores below.

I am trying to create a development site structure like this:

Live websites, the Master branch will be here:

```
/home/website1/public_html/
```

The stage devsite for the live website, which will have the stage branch, which when pushed into the master branch will bring the changes to the live site:

```
/home/dev/public_html/stage/site1
```

Each developer has his own directory and one or more development sites under it, and each devsite can have multiple branches:

```
/home/dev/public_html/developer1/devsite1
/home/dev/public_html/developer1/devsite2

/home/dev/public_html/developer2/devsite1
/home/dev/public_html/developer2/devsite2
```

The purpose is that at any time each developer can swap around branches on their devsites to look at the changes and features.
When a project is complete, then, for example, changes from branch A on developer1/devsite1 get merged into stage/site1.
Also, at any time when developer2 is working developer2/devsite1 branch B, he can update that branch B with the changes from the branch A on developer1/devsite1.

BUT, for testing purposes, I have made the stage website the master, though the process, I believe, should still be the same.

---

The command I'm trying to use is "git worktree add", but I have spent at least a couple hours searching around for why it doesn't work for me, increasing my understanding and differentiating the results I get from it, but never succeeding.

So I take this command and fill it out based on documentation, where the argument -b means create a new branch, followed by the name of the new branch, then the path of the working directory I want that branch to be in and probably followed by the name of that branch there, somehow...

```
git worktree add -b branch1 /home/dev/public_html/stage/site1/
```

This immediately creates branch1 on the stage/site1 site and says :

```
fatal: the branch already exists.

git worktree add -b branch1 /home/dev/public_html/developer1/devsite1/ branch1
```

This just says:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'branch1'
```

---

P.S. I am new to Git and the terms regarding movement and position such as when something is pushed or when it is pulled, when it's downstream or upstream, etc. still slightly confuse me.

Comment: In typical git workflow, there is one worktree per repository.  Each developer will have their own repository; you can have a staging and a master repository. Switching from branch to branch within a repository updates the files in the worktree; you don't have a separate worktree for each branch.  The developers would push and pull to the staging repository, and you'd push from the staging to the master.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you need the different branches for each developer. Surely each developer will be working on their own machine.

Comment: Regardless of my above comment, the syntax for worktree is quite clear: the branch name passed with the -b parameter is the name of a new branch that will be created on the worktree. The <path> is where the branch will be checked out to and <branch> is the name of an existing branch. So git worktree add -b new_branch /home/dev/new_branch master would checkout the master branch to /home/dev/new_branch and would create the new_branch branch from master at that location.

Comment: Are you trying to coordinate development by multiple developers directly on a single shared server?

Comment: That's right, Chris, I forgot to point that out.
I can do it this way:
git worktree add -b newbranch1 /home/dev/public_html/developer1/devsite1/newdirectory master
But I need the devsite files in that folder, so I need the command to checkout in the devsite1 folder, not a new folder somewhere else.